# SVM Cross Validation Problem - Error in table(testingsvmmodel, testing) : all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am getting and error when trying to create a table to assess the results of my svm model. I am wondering if you could have a look as I have spent hours now trying to figure it out but can't (apologies for being such a noob).  My model is as follows:

```
smp_size <- floor(0.67 * nrow(Data))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Data)), size = smp_size)
training <- Data[train_ind, ]
testing <- Data[-train_ind, ]

svmmodel <- svm(Winner ~ Rank_Diff + Ace_Diff + DF_Diff + ServAc_Diff + 
WonServ_Diff + BreakPt_diff, data = training)

testingsvmmodel<- predict(svmmodel, data = testing)

svmtab <- table(testingsvmmodel, testing$Winner)
```

This is the error:

> Error in table(testingsvmmodel, testing$Winner) :
>         all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Sorry, not sure if i was clear here. i understand the error message but am not sure why I am getting it. As the testingsvmmodel variable here should be the same length as the testing$winner dataframe, so I am confused as to why I getting this error

Comment: have you checked `length(testingsvmmodel)` and `length(testing$Winner)`?

Comment: HI RAB, thanks for the reply. Just checked it there, and the lengths don't match as you suggested testingsvmmodel is 27607 and training is only12 .... I though the length referred to the number of rows, but obviously not. Do you know what action I could take to get around this problem?

Comment: Could you make the code reproducible with sample data and also include the libraries used?